# IF funtion in QueryDsl

Tags: querydsl

How to write this query in `queryDsl`

`select * from Table order by if(a = 0, b, a) desc`

I struggle with the `if(a = 0, b, a)` part

**SOLUTION**

`orderBy(Expressions.stringTemplate("if({0} = 0, {1}, {2})", a, b, a).desc())`

Comment: I Solved orderBy((new CaseBuilder().when(a.eq(0)).then(b).otherwise(a)).desc())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`orderBy((new CaseBuilder().when(a.eq(0)).then(b).otherwise(a)).desc())` is the preferred way to do this. Template expressions also work, but are more susceptible to query injection bugs.